# Python file.write(email + '\n') NameError: name 'email' is not defined

Tags: python

i get this error from my code i dont get it why it isnt working

```
with open("emails.txt",'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        grade_data = line.strip().split(':')
        email = grade_data[0]
        password = grade_data[1]

with open("emails_sorted.txt",'a') as file:
    print(Fore.YELLOW + "Sorting email...")
    file.write(email + '\n')

with open("passwords.txt",'a') as file:
    print(Fore.YELLOW + "Sorting password...")
    passwordspecial = password + '!'
    file.write(passwordspecial + '\n')

print(Fore.GREEN + "Done!")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're opening `emails_sorted.txt` *after* you've iterated through the contents of the other text files. You can fix this by either saving the data read from `emails.txt` and iterating through it again when you open `emails_sorted.txt` and `passwords.txt`:

```py
emails = []
passwords = []

with open("emails.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    for line in file.readlines():
        grade_data = line.strip().split(":")
        emails.append(grade_data[0])
        passwords.append(grade_data[1])

with open("emails_sorted.txt", "a", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    print(Fore.YELLOW + "Sorting email...")
    for email in emails:
        file.write(email + "\n")

with open("passwords.txt", "a", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    print(Fore.YELLOW + "Sorting password...")
    for password in passwords:
        passwordspecial = password + "!"
        file.write(passwordspecial + "\n")

print(Fore.GREEN + "Done!")
```

Answer (score 2):

In the shown code, `for line in file`, if file is empty, loop won't run, thus email won't be defined. Try to stop the process if file is empty, or set a default value for email